# Standard django forms error messages

Tags: python, django, validation

where a are standard error messages in django forms ?

And how can i use them in my custom validation ?

I mean errors like 'this field is required'

Thanks

EDIT:

currently i do this:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(QuoteForm, self).clean()

    country = cleaned_data['country']

    for key in COUNTRY_FIELDS[country]:
        if cleaned_data[key] == '':
            self._errors[key] = self.error_class(_('This field is required'))

    return cleaned_data
```

FIXED:
I added:

```
        self._errors[key] = self.error_class( [forms.Field.default_error_messages['required']])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`django.forms.fields.Field` and its subclasses have a `default_error_messages` class attribute.

It's a dict with keys like `required` and `invalid` and the error messages as values.

- `django.forms.fields.Field.default_error_messages` has `required`
- `IntegerField`, `FloatField`, `DateField`, `TimeField` each have its own `invalid`.
- `DecimalField` has `max_digits`, `max_decimal_places` and `max_whole_digits`
- etc.

[Browse the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py). Search the page for `default_error_messages`.

If you are subclassing a `Field`, you can, for example,

```
raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'])
```

In a field, `error_messages` contains `default_error_messages` of the field's class and its ancestors and any additional `error_messages` that were passed during field initialization.

If you want to reuse a `required` message outside a field, you could

```
from django.forms import fields 

raise ValidationError(fields.Field.default_error_messages['required'])
```

What messages did you want to reuse?

Comment: Why don't you post some code illustrating what do you want to do? You shouldn't worry about `error_class` usually.